# Write struct to csv file

Tags: csv, go

What is an idiomatic golang way to dump the struct into a csv file provided? I am inside a func where my struct is passed as interface{}:

```
func decode_and_csv(my_response *http.Response, my_struct interface{})
```

Why interface{}? - reading data from JSON and there could be a few different structs returned, so trying to write a generic enough function.

an example of my types:

```
type Location []struct {
    Name                   string `json: "Name"`
    Region                 string `json: "Region"`
    Type                   string `json: "Type"`
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you used a concrete type. You'll probably want to use the `encoding/csv` package, here is a relevant example; https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#example_Writer

As you can see, the `Write` method is expecting a `[]string` so in order to generate this, you'll have to either 1) provide a helper method or 2) reflect `my_struct`. Personally, I prefer the first method but it depends on your needs. If you want to go route two you can get all the fields on the struct an use them as the column headers, then iterate the fields getting the value for each, use `append` in that loop to add them to a `[]string` and then pass it to `Write` out side of the loop.

For the first option, I would define a `ToSlice` or something on each type and then I would make an interface call it `CsvAble` that requires the `ToSlice` method. Change the type in your method `my_struct CsvAble` instead of using the empty interface and then you can just call `ToSlice` on `my_struct` and pass the return value into `Write`. You could have that return the column headers as well (meaning you would get back a `[][]string` and need to iterate the outer dimension passing each `[]string` into `Write`) or you could require another method to satisfy the interface like `GetHeaders` that returns a `[]string` which is the column headers. If that were the case your code would look something like;

```
w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
headers := my_struct.GetHeaders()
values := my_struct.ToSlice()
if err := w.Write(headers); err != nil {
    //write failed do something
}
if err := w.Write(values); err != nil {
    //write failed do something
}
```

If that doesn't make sense let me know and I can follow up with a code sample for either of the two approaches.

Comment: Just in case, there is a function to get headers.

`
func getHeaders(location Location) (header []string) {
 e := reflect.ValueOf(&location).Elem()
 for i := 0; i < e.NumField(); i++ {
  varName := e.Type().Field(i).Name
  header = append(header, varName)
 }
 return header
}
`